# How can I display in an array in vb

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Dim textstring as String,warray() as String
 textstring=Range("A3").Value
 warray=split(textstring,"")
 If isDate(warray(0))=True Then
 Range("A4").Value=warray(1)
 End If
```

This code displays only one word, no other words are displayed.

Comment: Currently it is displaying only one word

Comment: What is Range("A3").Value?

Comment: Range which accepts a value from cell a3

Comment: Like 3:00 the big bang

Answer (score 4):

Typically, the vba [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function) is used to split a string into a multiple element array on a delimiter. If a space was used as the delimiter, a sentence or paragraph would be split into individual words.

You are providing a zero-length string (e.g. `""` ) as the delimiter. From the [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function):

> <sub>... If delimiter is a zero-length string, a single-element array containing the entire expression string is returned.</sub>

So if you want to actually split something into multiple pieces, you cannot use a zero-length string as the delimiter.

If you used a space as the delimiter and provided no other parameters, then your example would be split into four elements of the array. I suspect you only want to split off the time and leave the show title together. The **limit** parameter is used for this. A limit of 2 will split your original string into a time and a show title.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro3()
    Dim textstring As String, warray() As String
    textstring = Range("A3").Value
    warray = Split(expression:=textstring, delimiter:=" ", limit:=2)
    If IsDate(warray(0)) Then
        Range("A4").Value = warray(0)
        Range("A5").Value = warray(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thaks a lot.it helped me.can you refer me some macro learning web sites